# How to upload app developed in eclipse to phonegap for ios app?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I've downloaded node.js and also cordova.  I downloaded the latest version of phone gap.  When I did: 
    cordova platform add ios 
I got:

```
 "Downloading cordova library for ios...
Download complete
Creating ios project...
'C:\Users\Mario\cordova\lib\ios\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create' is not recognized as an internal   or         
external command, operable program or batch file.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Mario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova    \src\superspawn.js:112:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit(events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I've set the path in JAVA_HOME to the correct path and also made sure android platform and platform-tools are correct in the PATH.

In phonegap API docs it says, "To develop Cordova applications, you must install SDKs for each mobile platform you are targeting."  Are they saying we should download the Apple IOS SDK?  Is that even possible on a Windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only create iOS applications on a computer that has the iOS SDK (a mac) or through the phonegap build web service (http://build.phonegap.com)

Additionally you will need iOS developer account to deploy the application to a device or to the app store.

Comment: thank you, I've developed my app in Eclipse and when I tried to upload it to phonegap build, phonegap came back with the error that index.html is missing.  Eclipse doesn't include an index.html in Android Application.  Where should I put this file?  What should I put in it?

Comment: PhoneGap is for applications built with HTML/JS/CSS and then run through a native webview. If your app is not built like that, you cannot use it with PhoneGap.

Comment: ok.  Thanks.  I was under the impression that phonegap eliminated the need to use a mac(or PC) altogether in deploying apps for both platforms.  I've since learned about some paid services, etc.  Thanks again for your insight.